# Why the animation clip is not motion ? I can's add it to a state in Animator Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a new Animator Controller added the new Controller to the door object.
Now the door object have Animation and Animator components.

Then in the Animator window of the door i created two new empty States and named them Open and Close. When i click once on the Close state and click on Motion in the Inspector in the list i see the close and open animations. When i make double click on the close it's not adding the animation clip to the Motion.

Same thing with the open animation clip. Other animations from the list i can add without a problem.

[image: New animator controller]

[image: Animations list]

Comment: Unchecking on both animation clips on the Legacy property fixed it. But is it a good thing to uncheck the Legacy ?

Comment: yes, legacy checkbox is purely for old animation system